# React Native Redux - Passing variable into dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Given an App.js file with these code snippets for redux:

```
const initialState = {
    selection: ''
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'selection1':
            return { selection: 'selection1' }
        case 'selection2':
            return { selection: 'selection2' }
    }
    return state
}

const store = createStore(reducer)
```

and an Redux.js child component with a picker and redux dispatch:

```
<Picker onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.props.changeSelection(itemValue)}>
    <Picker.Item label="Option1" value="selection1">
    <Picker.Item label="Option2" value="selection2">
</Picker>


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        changeSelection: () => dispatch({ type: itemValue })
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to pass the itemValue that the picker switches to into the dispatch and then update the state in the App.js reducer. Is it correct to pass in itemValue into this.props.changeSelection() and then have it set as the type in the dispatcher?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change this line

```
changeSelection: () => dispatch({ type: itemValue })
```

by this line

```
changeSelection: (itemValue) => dispatch({ type: itemValue })
```

`changeSelection` should have one parameter which is the `itemValue`

By the way I think `itemValue` should not be set into the action `type`, it's more related to the action `payload` actually, you could dispatch an action like this

```
{ type: 'UPDATE_SELECTION', payload: itemValue }
```

then your reducer would be like this

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_SELECTION':
        return { ...state, selection: action.payload }
  }
  return state
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, really silly mistake then. Thanks for the help.